# Google Music not available for Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.2.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, google-play-store, google-play-music

I have Samsung Galaxy S (i9000) with Android 2.2.1 (Froyo).
Lately I got an invite to Google Music. Android app for Google Music requires 2.2.0, however Android Market keep saying my phone is not capable to run application.

Is there a way how to get Google Music Android client on my Samsung Galaxy S - ?

Comment: I thought it was not available outside of the US.

Comment: Well, the website works fine, I was allowed to upload my songs, and I can even listen to the music via in-browser player. So, it is available outside US. But not for Android device... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I understand Google might not like this, and probably it is not 100% politically correct answer, here is the link where you can download APK of Google Music.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1072655

If you enable installation from unknown sources, you can install the thing on your phone, without restrictions.

I tried and it worked. I was able to access my music uploaded to Google and even play it.
That means the restrictions are only settings in Android Market, everything else seems to be free of restrictions.

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround, but don't be surprised if that loophole gets closed. That said, I'm sure they are looking to open it up to more of the world eventually so probably don't care that much. Still, you'll not be able to get any technical assistance from Google if you run into problems. _Caveat Emptor_.

Answer (score 2):

I see exactly the same thing with a UK Galaxy S running Gingerbread 2.3.3.

From the 3rd paragraph of the [description of the app in the Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.music&hl=en):

> **Available in the U.S.** by invitation **only** and free for a limited time.

According to your profile you're not in the US, so it won't be listed as compatible with your device.